# VIM hide (not fold!) lines

Tags: vim

Is there a way to totally hide certain lines? I do not want folding, I one them to not be visible at all.

Example: I program with php; functions and class variables have phpdocs, and I hate how much vertical space lines with nothing but `/**` and `*/` can take. Thus I would like to not show them (and most likely some other things). Though I have doubts that that is possible...

Note: I know about global commands and they don't do what I want. You can one of printing of what I want. But I want lines hidden in the editing area.

Comment: While I don't have a direct answer for you, Vim is open source and extensible. Anything is possible with enough time and effort.

Comment: But isn't folding just perfect for your example of phpdocs: they are condensed to a single line, which serves as an important visual indication that "something's hidden there". Without this indication, this would be a dangerous feature. Also remember that Vim has to work equally well in the console, so any fancy GUI-indication won't work.

Comment: maybe you could do it with `conceal` or `fold`+`highlight` in background color, though it seems to be dirty. Some of the kind is definitely possible - i remember when i accidentally turned on folding in `AutomaticLatexPlugin` this feature drove me nuts.

Comment: @IngoKarkat it's not,at least with default foldtext it's annoying.Folded phpdocs look like `/**` which is of 0 use.And as I said I kinda want to see phpdoc itself,just not the damn lines that indicate start and end of it,I have syntax highlighting so I see that its comment,and starts with `*`,so I see 0 use of waisting display lines for `/**` and `*/`.I began trying to devise some foldtext that would show function line when folded from beginning of phpdoc to end of function,for now I haven't managed to get satisfactory result.Though seeing `*/` is of any use only when initially writing phpdoc.

Comment: Why not use a regex mapped to a hotkey to collapse/uncollapse the newlines? In practice it's the same. It seems pointless to say "it must be done *this way*" when doing it that way is impossible. You seem to explicitly prohibit the only reasonable way to approximat what you want.

Comment: If you are not afraid of checking new horizons, Spacemacs got a nice `<leader> c h` binding that completely hides (toggles) comments the way you described. And yes Spacemacs is perfect for someone used to develop under Vim.

Answer (score 11):

You can make comments invisible:

```
:hi! Comment guifg=bg ctermfg=white
```

Or

```
:hi! link Comment Ignore
```

Comment: @nye17 `:hi! link Comment Comment`

Answer (score 7):

I know this isn't really what you're asking for, but have you tried using folding with a blank `foldtext`? That way the lines a folded region appears like an empty line. To do this, set

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker=\/**,*\/
set foldtext='\ '
```

I prefer a foldtext which indicates that there's *something* there, possibly by making is look like a single commented line. In this case, replacing the first folded line with a single comment string `//` at the current indent level:

```
set foldtext=substitute(getline(v:foldstart),'\\/\\*\\*.*','\\/\\/','g'
```

I find this unobtrusive, while still reminding me that there is some hidden text.

Hope this helps.